# Multiple Authors on same post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a friend who has asked me to build a site for him and two friends to write movie reviews. I'm pretty good with Wordpress, so it was the obvious choice for the site. The only difficulty I have is that they each plan to write a review on the same movie, and I can't think of how to achieve multiple authors in one post.

I've checked out a few plugins such as Co-Author Plus which allows multiple authors credited to the same post, but it doesn't provide the functionality for keeping each author's content separate.

The only solution I can think of is to use custom fields, but I would prefer if the authors can use the main content editor for their reviews. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It should be better to have 1 review = 1 post, no ?

Comment: Preferably, yes. But how would I group them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, it should be better to have 1 review = 1 post.

So, I think the best way to achieve this should be to create post types :

- movie
- review, with a movie reference field

And modify post template to display movie and associated reviews on the same page.

An alternate solution should be to use taxonomy to handle movies and attach post to them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with trying to figure out how to do this as well and I followed soju's advice and came up with a solution.  There might be a better solution to this, but this is how I went about it.  Me and my friend are doing an anime review blog and both me and him will be writing a review on the same anime.

I first created two post types:

- anime: main page on the specific anime, like the description, pictures, etc.
- reviews: the author's review on the anime.  the options i have enabled on here are the editor, the title, and the author.  Along with the associated anime taxonomy.  That's all that's needed here

Then I created a taxonomy for anime titles so when a user needs to write a review on an anime that hasn't been added as a review yet they can add the title into the taxonomy.

I associated the taxonomy to both post_types and wala!  That's pretty much all you need.

So now when you want to write a new review for a new anime you add a anime post type first and write down what the anime is about and include pictures etc. Add the title to the taxonomy and check it.  After that you then create a new post of the post type reviews and write your review, remember to check the correct title in your taxonomy for what anime this is going to, then you are ready to go!

Problem 1:  How do I include this into my loop?

Well you don't want to include both post types in your loop you just want to include posts and the other post type anime in your loop so you do the following in your functions.php file:

```
function include_custom_post_types( $query ) { 
    global $wp_query;
    // Get all custom post types
    $custom_post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
    // Get all post types
    $post_types = get_post_types();

    // If what you are getting is a category or a tag or that there are no custom
    // post types you just want to set the post types to be the current post types          
    if ( (is_category() || is_tag()) && empty( $custom_post_type ))
       $query->set( 'post_type' , $post_types );

    // Set the custom post types you want to ignore
    $ignore_types = array('reviews');

    //Unset the post types that are gonna be ignored
    foreach($post_types as $key=>$type)
    {
       if(in_array($type,$ignore_types))
       {
          unset($post_types[$key]);
       }
    }

    // Set the post types for the query
    if ( (is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters']) || is_feed())
         $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types);

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'include_custom_post_types' );
```

Problem 2:  How do I display the reviews?

I solved this by creating another single.php file and renamed it to single-post_type_name.php.  So in this case i created a single-anime.php file for my post type anime.  Then in place of the contents i want to get all the reviews for this specific anime so I added the following within the file in the main content area:

```
<?php  
    //You grab the taxonomy that you have selected for this post
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'animes_reviewed');
    // This is the args array for the criteria that the posts need to be in
   $args = array(
       // This is the post type of where your reviews are at
       post_type' => 'reviews',
       // this is for searching the taxonomy usually it's 
       // taxonomy_name => checked_taxonomy
       'anime' => $terms[0]->name, 
       'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    // Grab the posts
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    //Here I echo out the information for debugging purpose, but 
    //Here is where you can do HTML to display your reviews
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        echo($post->post_content);
        the_author_meta( 'nickname', $post->post_author);
    }
?>
```

You can do a lot more with this adding more taxonomies etc.  I have actually implemented an episode review by just adding a taxonomy and adding a criteria to look for in the post section.  Hopefully this will help you out, might be a bit late though :(  Thanks soju for recommending the custom post types!